# java link activated event behavior difference

Tags: java, swing, event-handling, batik

Good evening everyone;

I have JSVGCanvas (component from batik framework) on i am displaying an svg document on canvas with links. I would like to open a new window(jframe) on my swing when a link clicked. therefore i am using a linkActivated event. However, my problem is

```
private JPanel contentPane;
File f;
JSVGCanvas svgCanvas;

/**
 * Launch the application.
 */
public static void main(String[] args) {
    EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
        public void run() {
            try {
                trialgui frame = new trialgui();
                frame.setVisible(true);
            } catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    });
}

/**
 * Create the frame.
 */
public trialgui() {
    setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    setBounds(100, 100, 452, 418);
    contentPane = new JPanel();
    contentPane.setBorder(new EmptyBorder(5, 5, 5, 5));
    contentPane.setLayout(new BorderLayout(0, 0));
    setContentPane(contentPane);
    f = new  File("./links.svg");

    svgCanvas = new JSVGCanvas();

    if(f.exists()==true){System.out.println("file is ok");}
    try {

        svgCanvas.setURI(f.toURL().toString());

    } catch (MalformedURLException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    svgCanvas.setDocumentState(JSVGCanvas.ALWAYS_DYNAMIC);
    contentPane.add(svgCanvas, BorderLayout.CENTER);
    svgCanvas.setMySize(new Dimension(100,100));

    JButton btnNewButton = new JButton("New button");
    btnNewButton.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent arg0) {
            try {
                svgCanvas.setURI(f.toURL().toString());
            } catch (MalformedURLException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            }


        }
    });
    contentPane.add(btnNewButton, BorderLayout.NORTH);

    svgCanvas.addLinkActivationListener(new LinkActivationListener() {

        @Override
        public void linkActivated(LinkActivationEvent arg0) {
            System.out.println("here is working");

            try {

                JFrame gh = new JFrame();
                gh.setVisible(true);
                f = new  File("./links.svg");
                svgCanvas.setURI(f.toURL().toString());
            } catch (MalformedURLException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            } 
            System.out.println("here");
        }
    });
}
```

when user clicks on a link svgcanvas displays the link within same canvas.So in order to prevent this i set initial svg svgCanvas.setURI(f.toURL().toString()); when link activated triggered. However, referenced link appears in same canvas because of method is not working. If i put the same method in a button event when i click to button it bring backs the initial svg to my svgcanvas.

Could anyone tell me why this event acts different than button event and how can i possibly solve this problem ?

Regards ....